# Predicate in FetchResults for Core Data has no effect

Tags: ios, core-data, swift3

I have a Core Data app that basically works for retrieving data, but when I apply a predicate there is no filtering. In other words, the same results are returned regardless of the filter.  Any suggestions?

```
lazy var frc: NSFetchedResultsController<Report> =
    {
        let context = self.app.persistentContainer.viewContext

        let req: NSFetchRequest<Report> = Report.fetchRequest()
        req.fetchBatchSize = 20


        let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "status", ascending:true)
        req.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

        let filter = self.app.currentFilter
        //print(filter!)
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "status == %@", filter)
        req.predicate = predicate

        let afrc = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: req, managedObjectContext: context, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: "reports")
        afrc.delegate = self
        do
        {
            try afrc.performFetch()
        }
        catch
        {
            fatalError("Abort while fetching report")
        }
        return afrc
}()
```

The status attribute for the Report entity is a `String`.

Comment: Looking at your line `//print(filter!)`, I presume you are aware that this lazy getter code only runs once.  Are you changing the `filter` after that?  And is that when you get the unexpected results?

Comment: Yes.  I tried just using a static string as well. I may have solved my problem but now I'm trying to figure out why I solved it. I added a relationship to the model and now the predicates are working, but the relationship is not on the predicate filter item and I have not changed the above code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following up to the two comments above, maybe the answer is in the [Apple documentation for NSFetchedResultsController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsfetchedresultscontroller).  Read the section *Modifying the Fetch Request*, noting in particular that

*You cannot simply change the fetch request to modify the results.*

Comment: That basically answered the question but I'm still struggling. I get inconsistent results. In one place I can modify the request (before I re-read the docs) and it works fine - so far. I'm still missing something. In that documentation it appears to state that if you are not using caching you should be able to change the fetch request at will. I changed the cache name to nil, but the results aren't exactly what I expected.

Comment: Maybe you're doing a performFetch() in the one place where it "works fine"

Comment: Also, I'd like to point out again that all of the code you posted, everything between the {...}(), is a closure that runs at most *once* in the lifetime of the enclosing object/class, to initialize frc.  Modifying the fetch request must therefore be elsewhere.